# Facebook won't let me post in other languages

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am an admin on several Facebook pages, and have previously been able to post in different languages.

However the last year or so, it is as if this function has frozen. When I click on the "write post in another language", I get English as a default but when trying to change or add any languages, it is as if it freezes. I can't search for any languages at all.

I tried contacting Facebook, but they haven't responded.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 1):

From [Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/181155025579876?helpref=related):

> You'll need to be an [admin](https://www.facebook.com/help/289207354498410?helpref=faq_content) to write a post for your Page in more than one language. People who view your post will see the language that's most relevant to them based on their language settings and locale.
>
> You'll need to first make sure you've allowed posts in multiple languages:
>
> 1. Click **Settings** at the top of your Page.
> 2. From **General**, click **Post in Multiple Languages**.
> 3. Click to check the box next to A**llow people who manage this Page to write posts in multiple languages**.
> 4. Click **Save Changes**.
>
> To create a post for your Page in more than one language:
>
> 1. Write your post at the top of your Page's timeline. This will be the default language for the post.
> 2. Click **Write post in another language**, then click **Select**(down arrow symbol) and select a language.
> 3. Click **Write post in another language** to add another language or click **Publish**.
>
> Note: People whose primary language isn't included as an additional language will see the post in its default language. For example, if the default language for your post is English and you also wrote your post in Spanish and French, people whose primary language is German will see the post in English.

Comment: Any idea how to add languages to already published posts?